# Configure ckeditor in rails to write in Markdown syntax as opposed to HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ckeditor, markdown

In one part of my application I am successfully using creditor.  It properly takes the text typed in and converts it into html format.

User Types in the content:

[image: User types in content]

And it properly saves the content in html syntax:

[image: html_syntax]

In another place in my application I want to again use ckeditor.  However: this time I want the content to be converted into Markdown syntax as opposed to HTML syntax.  Is this possible?  If so, how do you specify that configuration for this one place in the application (as opposed to globally specifying this rule because everywhere else I want ckeditor to continue converting the content into html).

I did look within the ruby gems [ckeditor docs](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor).  I also looked through the [ckeditor documentation on options](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config), however looking through that was a bit overwhelming to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was creating a script that converted the database fields in my application that were in markdown syntax into html syntax. I did this with the [redcarpet](https://rubygems.org/gems/redcarpet) Gem and the [rdiscount](https://rubygems.org/gems/rdiscount) Gem.  With those fields now saved in html syntax instead of markdown syntax, I rendered the text just like I do everywhere else where ckeditor is used.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have to add the [markdown addon](http://ckeditor.com/addon/markdown) as it is not part of ckeditor, then follow the [documentation](https://github.com/hectorguo/CKEditor-Markdown-Plugin).